# How to append a string to the result of file_get_contents

Tags: php

I would like to know to to append a string of text at the beginning of the result gave by

```
file_get_contents
```

in my case

```
$file = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: `$file = 'sting' . file_get_contents($url);`

Comment: `$contents = 'prepended value ' . file_get_contents($file);`?

Comment: So you mean _prepend_. Well, how do you do it to _any_ string? -1 for no basic research

Comment: Seriously? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @GibboK: The PHP manual is open to everybody. Stack Overflow is not to be treated as an alternative to reading the documentation.

Comment: @GibboK: I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: Thanks  Lightness Races in Orbit for your time on this basic question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do like this--

```
$file = "Some text content".file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: This is not working